# Add columns to mySQL table with loops

Tags: mysql, loops, alter, sequential

I'm fairly new to mySQL. Let's say I'm adding columns to my table like so:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD client_input_2.0_1 LONGTEXT;
```

And I would like to add a number of similar sequential columns, i.e.

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD client_input_2.0_2 LONGTEXT;
ALTER TABLE table ADD client_input_2.0_3 LONGTEXT;
ALTER TABLE table ADD client_input_2.0_4 LONGTEXT;
```

etc. all the way up to a large enough number that this will take quite some time if I do this manually. In my case, 2.0 represents a section/part, and the last number represents a question number, which could be anywhere from 1-50 or so depending on the section, so manually creating this table would take a lot of time.

Is there a way for me to do this in a script using some sort of loop, incrementing the col# each time?

Much appreciated,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited code

try using a stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS RepeatLoopProc$$
CREATE PROCEDURE RepeatLoopProc()
  BEGIN
          DECLARE x  INT;
          DECLARE str  VARCHAR(255);
          Declare @sql nvarchar(4000);
          SET x = 0;

          REPEAT
                      SET str =  '';
                      SET  str = CONCAT(str,'client_input_2.0_',x);
                      SET  x = x + 1;
                      set @sql='ALTER TABLE table_name ADD '+ str +' column-definition';
                      exec sp_executesql @sql;
          UNTIL x  > 50
          END REPEAT;

  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: While that would save me a few keystrokes, it would still take quite a bit of time manually for the number of columns I will need. Is there a way to do this slightly more procedurally?

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you should use another approach:

ALTER TABLE table ADD col LONGTEXT, ADD col_index INT.

and use col_index to track the col's purpose

Comment: While I really like that approach, I'm not sure that will work in my situation (I simplified a bit too much in my question). My table is a little more monstrous than that... My real column names are client_input_2.0_13_c where 2 represents a section number, the '.0' represents the part of that section, and '13' represents the question number, which there may be up to 50 or so in a section...